# Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record"

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, record

It keeps on giving me the error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record"

I am not sure what the problem is? I am trying to record the sound right when the counter reaches 1 after a picture is taken.

```
static int counter;
//counter will always be zero it think unless it is assigned.


if (counter == 0){

dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{
    // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.
    [[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoOrientation:[[(AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *)[[self previewView] layer] connection] videoOrientation]];

    // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
    [AVCamViewController setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];

    // Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {//[AVCaptureSession snapStillImage];
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
        }
        NSLog(@"i");
    }];
});

    if (!_audioRecorder.recording)
{
   //start recording as part of still image

    _playButton.enabled = NO;
    _stopButton.enabled = YES;
    [_audioRecorder record];

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        //do nothing just counting
    }

    //stop the recording
}

}

else if (counter == 1)

{
    [self recordForDuration:5];
}


}
```

Comment: Was this using the simulator?

Comment: @MarkMcCorkle, gotcha!

Comment: yes it was using a simulator!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error is because you use an emulator, you need use an device

Regards

Comment: Running on a device fixed it for me

Comment: This happens to me on device.

Comment: I use real device and has this error

Answer (score 4):

Make sure there is only one instance of `AVCaptureSession` running.

Answer (score 2):

Having your device restrict the camera access under "Settings > General > Restrictions" will also give you this error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when I was trying AVFoundation on a Mac, using a Mac Catalyst app. That is documented and intended behaviour, apparently:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124652#389519

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture

> This issue behaves as intended. We do document that we are not listing
>   devices in Catalyst mode. See Important iPad apps running in macOS
>   cannot use the AVFoundation Capture classes. These apps should instead
>   use UIImagePickerController for photo and video capture.

Answer (score 0):

I can be related with camera, You forget get info about device camera