# IOS catalyst avcapturedevice can't realize the function of scanning QR code. It happened in Catalina

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, macos-catalina, avcapturedevice

IOS catalyst avcapturedevice can't realize the function of scanning QR code. It happened in Catalina. How to realize the function of uiimagepickercontroller scanning QR code

1. This is Catalina's error report
   Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Record, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try recording again.}
2. Some netizens said that uiimagepickercontroller can be used to scan QR code. How can this be realized?

[Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11814 "Cannot Record"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176738/error-domain-avfoundationerrordomain-code-11814-cannot-record)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.This is how I solved it. Judge avcapturedevice.
```

'AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]; if (device == nil && [del isRunningOnMacOSX]) { [self initImagePickerController]; return; }'

```
2.Get QR code content after taking photos

(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey,id> *)info { UIImage *pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] ?: info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; CIImage *detectImage = [CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)]; CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow}]; CIQRCodeFeature *feature = (CIQRCodeFeature *)[detector featuresInImage:detectImage options:nil].firstObject; [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ if (feature.messageString) { [self onConnectionOrLicenseScanned:feature.messageString]; } }]; }
```